# Is there a standard symbol for a pressure sensor?

Tags: schematics, symbol, transducer

I am using Eagle to design a PCB that includes an [analog pressure sensor](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Honeywell/SSCDANN015PGAA5/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvhQj7WZhFIADdMYlPf938/Ai5frIiDCV0=). However, I can't seem to find if there is any standard symbol for the device. There isn't anything on the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/187/SSC_Analog-191397.pdf). I began to browse the web without much luck. Some block diagrams represented them as a simple circle with an "X" inside. Some schematics showed them as a circle or a circle with an arrow inside.

I also looked to see if there was a symbol for a generic transducer. Results included what I thought was the symbol for a piezo oscillator, as well as more circles with symbols inside.

Is there a standard symbol? If not, what is my best bet? Should I draw a circle with an arrow or letter "P" or something? Would it be better off to draw a block and label the appropriate pins, like some ICs?

Comment: I think that the best reference for something like this would be [IEC 60617](http://std.iec.ch/iec60617) (or your country's relevant standard, which is probably based on that anyway). Unfortunately, the database is paid access only (which never made sense to me for what is supposed to be a universal standard)

Comment: Thank you. I wondered if something like that existed. It's a shame it's paid though. Especially with all the different transistor symbols and grounds/returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a standard symbol for a pressure sensor.

Usually, it's drawn as an IC.

[image]

It's a good idea to indicate in the schematic that this is a sensor, and therefore something special. You can make a text block next to the symbol saying what the sensor is sensing.  If you know what kind of sensing element the sensor is based on, you can draw an icon of the sensing element in the schematic symbol.  If it's a MEMS pressure sensor like yours, you can draw a bridge on it.  (Another example.  If you know that some other sensor is based on a phototransistor, you can draw a phototransistor on it.)